# Android encryption framework for encrypting large strings with user authentication only when decrypting

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography, rsa, biometrics

I want to encrypt and store a token which is longer than what RSA permits but I can't use AES because if I want to secure it with biometrics then I have to ask for user authentication even when I am encrypting the value (and not only when decrypting it as with RSA).

I am using the RxFingerprint framework and I get this error:

> ```
> Caused by: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: input must be > under 256 bytes
> ```

with this code:

```
Disposable disposable = RxFingerprint.encrypt(EncryptionMethod.RSA, this, keyName, stringToEncrypt)
                   .subscribe(encryptionResult -> {
                       switch (encryptionResult.getResult()) {
                           case FAILED:
                               setStatusText("Fingerprint not recognized, try again!");
                               break;
                           case HELP:
                               setStatusText(encryptionResult.getMessage());
                               break;
                           case AUTHENTICATED:
                               setStatusText("Successfully authenticated!");
                               break;
                       }
                   }, throwable -> {
                       Log.e("ERROR", "authenticate", throwable);
                       setStatusText(throwable.getMessage());
                   });
```

I ve seen that some suggest splitting the large string into smaller but I ve read that this is not so safe.
I would like to store my large string in a way that can be secured by biometrics but only when reading the value, not when writing it.

Comment: I don't know why splitting up the strings wouldn't be ok, but if that isn't an option, why not compress your strings before encrypting them?

Comment: *...but I can't use AES because if I want to secure it with biometrics then I have to ask for user authentication even when I am encrypting the value...* That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @JamesKPolk "RSA encryption allows you to encrypt a value without any user action. The data to encrypt can be encrypted and a user won't need to authenticate oneself by touching the fingerprint sensor. The encrypted data can only be decrypted again when the user authenticates by using the fingerprint sensor on their device." https://github.com/Mauin/RxFingerprint

Comment: @ChrisStillwell could you provide this as an answer? I think it's working! (Will confirm it as answer as soon I confirm I get the same value back again)

Comment: You could use RSA to wrap an AES key "without user interaction" then decrypt the AES symmetric key upon authentication for decrypting the entirety of the ciphertext

Comment: [Hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem)

Comment: @Apostolos Your basic assumption seems to be that you have one RSA key pair and one AES key (stored encr. by RSA). However you don't have to use it this way. You can generate one AES key per message you want to encrypt and then encrypt the key via RSA and save it together with the AES encrypted message.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting your strings shouldn't be an issue. I'll leave the implementation up to you, but the basic idea would be:

```
int maxStringSize = 255;
for(int i = 0; i < myString.length; i += maxStringSize){
  int end = i + maxStringSize;
  if (myString.length < end) end = myString.length;
  doEncrypt(myString.substring(i, end));
}
```

Comment: This won't work, at least not reliably. This produces substrings of 256 *characters* whereas `doEncrypt` needs substrings whose utf-8 encoding is less than or equal to 255 *bytes*. Actually, it needs to be <= 245 bytes.